# Runing C program in Terminal

Tags: command-line, c

If I have a program written in C, how can I run this program in a terminal with just a single word (the program's name), no matter where it is on the system?

Comment: Add the path to the program to $PATH.

Comment: What you really want is to have the location of your program added to `$PATH` variable, as Pilot6 properly said. See this   http://askubuntu.com/q/60218/295286

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html

As Pilot6 and Serg wrote in comment, You have to expand your `$PATH` system variable and compile program in release mode. When you will have this done, you will call `myProgram` and your system should check if it exists ind `$PATH` directories; it will eventually run it if it exists, or show error "unknown command" if it doesn't.